# matlab: how to fix my function that has to return the mean/mode/median of a vector

Tags: matlab

I was given a problem to find the mean, mode, and median of a single vector input in matlab. My function saves these datapoints as 3 separate variables, but I get an error each time. Any tips on how to correct this?

```
function mean_mode_median(v) 

  v_mean = mean(v);
  v_mode = mode(v);
  v_median = median(v);
  
  disp(v_mean);
  disp(v_mode);
  disp(v_median);
  
  end
```

function call:

```
datapoints = [ 11 22 33 44 33 12 32 14 33 14];


disp(mean_mode_median(datapoints));
```

The error is not enough input arguments and too many output arguments.

Comment: What's the error being displayed? It works perfect for me. Can you show us your function call?

Comment: Common problems can including naming the script the same name as the function, or not putting local functions at the bottom of the script.

Comment: Remove `disp()` from `disp(mean_mode_median(datapoints));`

Comment: The `mean_mode_median` function does not return anything, you can't `disp` it.

Comment: To function prototype to return outputs follows: `function [Output 1, Output 2, Output_3,...] = functionName(Input_1,Input_2,Input_3,...)`

Answer (score 3):

Description: `disp(X)` displays the value of variable `X` without printing the variable name. More details please refer to https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html

Nomally, the `X` is a Matrix of numbers or strings.

In your case, `mean_mode_median(v)` has no return value, it means `disp()` will accept nothing. So the error meassage is "not enough input arguments and too many output arguments".

Two solutions:

1.Keep your function, and use `mean_mode_median(datapoints)` to display 3 separate variables.

2.Change your function to a more practical one, use `[v_mean, v_mode, v_median] = mean_mode_median(datapoints)` to receive variables and then display them.

```
function [v_mean, v_mode, v_median] = mean_mode_median(v) 
v_mean = mean(v);
v_mode = mode(v);
v_median = median(v);
end
```